# GStreamer Python: gi.repository.GLib.GError: gst_parse_error: no element "appsrc" on OSX

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, gstreamer

I'm trying to setup a RTSP stream in Python with OpenCV. I found [this repository](https://github.com/prabhakar-sivanesan/OpenCV-rtsp-server/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aclosed) which I started from as an example. I'm pretty sure the code in there is not entirely written by that person, because I found some older sources with the same code.
However, I took that as a base to get familiar with everything.

Here is the full (very slightly altered) Python script I'm trying to run:

```py
import gi
import cv2 as cv
import argparse

gi.require_versions({
  # 'Gtk': '3.0',
  'Gst': '1.0',
  'GstRtspServer': '1.0',
  'GLib': '2.0'
})
from gi.repository import Gst, GstRtspServer, GLib

class StreamFactory(GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory):
  def __init__(self, **properties):
    super(StreamFactory, self).__init__(**properties)
    self.cap = cv.VideoCapture(0) # 0 is the default camera
    self.number_frames = 0
    self.fps = opt.fps
    self.duration = 1 / self.fps * Gst.SECOND # duration of a frame in nanoseconds
    self.launch_string = 'appsrc name=source is-live=true block=true format=GST_FORMAT_TIME ' \
                      'caps=video/x-raw,format=BGR,width={},height={},framerate={}/1 ' \
                      '! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ' \
                      '! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency ' \
                      '! rtph264pay config-interval=1 name=pay0 pt=96' \
                      .format(opt.image_width, opt.image_height, self.fps)

  def on_need_data(self, src, length):
    if self.cap.isOpened():
      ret, frame = self.cap.read()
      if ret:
        frame = cv.resize(frame, (640, 480))
        data = frame.tostring()
        buf = Gst.Buffer.new_allocate(None, len(data), None)
        buf.fill(0, data)
        timestamp = self.number_frames * self.duration
        buf.pts = int(timestamp)
        buf.dts = int(timestamp)
        buf.offset = timestamp
        self.number_frames += 1
        retval = src.emit('push-buffer', buf)

        if retval != Gst.FlowReturn.OK:
          print(retval)

  def do_create_element(self, url):
    return Gst.parse_launch(self.launch_string)

  def do_configure(self, rtsp_media):
    self.number_frames = 0
    appsrc = rtsp_media.get_element().get_child_by_name('source')
    appsrc.connect('need-data', self.on_need_data)

class GstServer(GstRtspServer.RTSPServer):
  def __init__(self, **properties):
    super(GstServer, self).__init__(**properties)
    self.factory = StreamFactory()
    self.factory.set_shared(True)
    self.get_mount_points().add_factory(opt.stream_uri, self.factory)
    self.attach(None)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--device_id", required=True, help="device id for the video device or video file location")
parser.add_argument("--fps", required=True, help="fps of the camera", type = int)
parser.add_argument("--image_width", required=True, help="video frame width", type = int)
parser.add_argument("--image_height", required=True, help="video frame height", type = int)
parser.add_argument("--port", default=8554, help="port to stream video", type = int)
parser.add_argument("--stream_uri", default = "/video_stream", help="rtsp video stream uri")
opt = parser.parse_args()

# GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)
server = GstServer()
loop = GLib.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```

The result of running this is that it starts, but as soon as I connect to the server, it throws the following exception:

[image: error output]

Currently I only have access to an M1 Mac, so I can't confirm it myself, but according to some issues I found (like [this one](https://github.com/prabhakar-sivanesan/OpenCV-rtsp-server/issues/7)), might be architecture related, although I'm not entirely positive about it because I also saw [this issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/109283) and it looks that it's indeed outdated and not related, because if I run `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! autovideosink` it works just fine, unlike what's been said in that issue.

I installed `gstreamer` + all dependencies via HomeBrew, but I also verified I get the same result building from scratch without HomeBrew.

All the libraries I've installed so far with homebrew (I'll just post the complete list here, but keep in mind not all dependencies are related to this issue):

[image: brew list]

And here is also my Python dependency list:

```
✖ pip3 freeze
docutils==0.19
numpy==1.24.2
opencv-python==4.7.0.72
pycairo==1.23.0
PyGObject==3.42.2
six==1.16.0
```

On python version: `3.9.16.final.0`, also tried latest `3.11` version.
OSX version: `13.0.1 (22A400)`

I also verified that the `appsrc` plugin is available to gst using the `gst-inspect` command, and it looks like it is:

```
✖ gst-inspect-1.0 appsrc
Factory Details:
  Rank                     none (0)
  Long-name                AppSrc
  Klass                    Generic/Source
  Description              Allow the application to feed buffers to a pipeline
  Author                   David Schleef <ds@schleef.org>, Wim Taymans <wim.taymans@gmail.com>
  Documentation            https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/app/appsrc.html

Plugin Details:
  Name                     app
  Description              Elements used to communicate with applications
  Filename                 /opt/homebrew/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstapp.dylib
  Version                  1.22.0
  License                  LGPL
  Source module            gst-plugins-base
  Documentation            https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/app/
  Source release date      2023-01-23
  Binary package           GStreamer Base Plug-ins source release
  Origin URL               Unknown package origin

GObject
 +----GInitiallyUnowned
       +----GstObject
             +----GstElement
                   +----GstBaseSrc
                         +----GstAppSrc

Implemented Interfaces:
  GstURIHandler

Pad Templates:
  SRC template: 'src'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      ANY

Element has no clocking capabilities.

URI handling capabilities:
  Element can act as source.
  Supported URI protocols:
    appsrc

Pads:
  SRC: 'src'
    Pad Template: 'src'

Element Properties:
  block               : Block push-buffer when max-bytes are queued
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: false
  blocksize           : Size in bytes to read per buffer (-1 = default)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Unsigned Integer. Range: 0 - 4294967295 Default: 4096
  caps                : The allowed caps for the src pad
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Caps (NULL)
  current-level-buffers: The number of currently queued buffers
                        flags: readable
                        Unsigned Integer64. Range: 0 - 18446744073709551615 Default: 0
  current-level-bytes : The number of currently queued bytes
                        flags: readable
                        Unsigned Integer64. Range: 0 - 18446744073709551615 Default: 0
  current-level-time  : The amount of currently queued time
                        flags: readable
                        Unsigned Integer64. Range: 0 - 18446744073709551615 Default: 0
  do-timestamp        : Apply current stream time to buffers
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: false
  duration            : The duration of the data stream in nanoseconds (GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE if unknown)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Unsigned Integer64. Range: 0 - 18446744073709551615 Default: 18446744073709551615
  emit-signals        : Emit need-data, enough-data and seek-data signals
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: true
  format              : The format of the segment events and seek
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Enum "GstFormat" Default: 2, "bytes"
                           (0): undefined        - GST_FORMAT_UNDEFINED
                           (1): default          - GST_FORMAT_DEFAULT
                           (2): bytes            - GST_FORMAT_BYTES
                           (3): time             - GST_FORMAT_TIME
                           (4): buffers          - GST_FORMAT_BUFFERS
                           (5): percent          - GST_FORMAT_PERCENT
  handle-segment-change: Whether to detect and handle changed time format GstSegment in GstSample. User should set valid GstSegment in GstSample. Must set format property as "time" to enable this property
                        flags: readable, writable, changeable only in NULL or READY state
                        Boolean. Default: false
  is-live             : Whether to act as a live source
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: false
  leaky-type          : Whether to drop buffers once the internal queue is full
                        flags: readable, writable, changeable only in NULL or READY state
                        Enum "GstAppLeakyType" Default: 0, "none"
                           (0): none             - GST_APP_LEAKY_TYPE_NONE
                           (1): upstream         - GST_APP_LEAKY_TYPE_UPSTREAM
                           (2): downstream       - GST_APP_LEAKY_TYPE_DOWNSTREAM
  max-buffers         : The maximum number of buffers to queue internally (0 = unlimited)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Unsigned Integer64. Range: 0 - 18446744073709551615 Default: 0
  max-bytes           : The maximum number of bytes to queue internally (0 = unlimited)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Unsigned Integer64. Range: 0 - 18446744073709551615 Default: 200000
  max-latency         : The maximum latency (-1 = unlimited)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer64. Range: -1 - 9223372036854775807 Default: -1
  max-time            : The maximum amount of time to queue internally (0 = unlimited)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Unsigned Integer64. Range: 0 - 18446744073709551615 Default: 0
  min-latency         : The minimum latency (-1 = default)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer64. Range: -1 - 9223372036854775807 Default: -1
  min-percent         : Emit need-data when queued bytes drops below this percent of max-bytes
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Unsigned Integer. Range: 0 - 100 Default: 0
  name                : The name of the object
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: "appsrc0"
  num-buffers         : Number of buffers to output before sending EOS (-1 = unlimited)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer. Range: -1 - 2147483647 Default: -1
  parent              : The parent of the object
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Object of type "GstObject"
  size                : The size of the data stream in bytes (-1 if unknown)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer64. Range: -1 - 9223372036854775807 Default: -1
  stream-type         : the type of the stream
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Enum "GstAppStreamType" Default: 0, "stream"
                           (0): stream           - GST_APP_STREAM_TYPE_STREAM
                           (1): seekable         - GST_APP_STREAM_TYPE_SEEKABLE
                           (2): random-access    - GST_APP_STREAM_TYPE_RANDOM_ACCESS
  typefind            : Run typefind before negotiating (deprecated, non-functional)
                        flags: readable, writable, deprecated
                        Boolean. Default: false

Element Signals:
  "need-data" :  void user_function (GstElement* object,
                                     guint arg0,
                                     gpointer user_data);
  "enough-data" :  void user_function (GstElement* object,
                                       gpointer user_data);
  "seek-data" :  gboolean user_function (GstElement* object,
                                         guint64 arg0,
                                         gpointer user_data);

Element Actions:
  "push-buffer" :  GstFlowReturn user_function (GstElement* object,
                                                GstBuffer* arg0);
  "push-buffer-list" :  GstFlowReturn user_function (GstElement* object,
                                                     GstBufferList* arg0);
  "push-sample" :  GstFlowReturn user_function (GstElement* object,
                                                GstSample* arg0);
  "end-of-stream" :  GstFlowReturn user_function (GstElement* object);
```

Last thing I've tried is to run the command directly from CLI instead of calling it via Python and it looks like its running without crashing:

```
❯ gst-launch-1.0 appsrc name=source is-live=true block=true format=GST_FORMAT_TIME caps=video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 name=pay0 pt=96
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Redistribute latency...
^Chandling interrupt.
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
Execution ended after 0:00:46.577237000
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Has anyone solved this issue or made more progress on this? I don't really know where else to open an issue related to this, because the original repo owner where I got the sample script from, doesn't seem to have a clue what is actually happening with the code. Opening another issue in the homebrew repo also seems wrong, because it doesn't look like it's a homebrew issue (anymore), and the current issue is closed and not accessible to comment on. GStreamer repo also doesn't allow for issues to be opened.

I'm going to try to also verify that it's happening on an intel mac and/or x86_64 ubuntu systems when I get the chance, but in the meantime, all pointers are welcome :)

Comment: Not fluent with Python, but can it be that the `StreamFactory` class runs it's init function before `Gst.init(None)` is called? But it seems okay.. but maybe that particular GStreamer install that python loads scans then wrong plugin directory.

Comment: I also have an M1 Macbook and it works fine with me

Comment: @FlorianZwoch Was facing the same problem, and your adivce solved the issue for me. Thanks.